# ¿Cómo se denomina a un licenciado en derecho que no ejerce?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

He estado buscando un término genérico para designar a un "licenciado en derecho sin ejercicio profesional", como alguien que acaba de terminar los estudios correspondientes, pero todas las opciones que he encontrado conllevan un ejercicio profesional. Así,

[**Abogado**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=07TG2dg)

> 1. m. y f. Licenciado en derecho que ofrece profesionalmente asesoramiento jurídico y que ejerce la defensa de las partes en los procesos judiciales o en los procedimientos administrativos.

[**Jurista**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MePq85r)

> 1. m. y f. Persona que ejerce una profesión jurídica.

[**Letrado**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NAwog2I)

> 6. m. y f. abogado (‖ licenciado en derecho).
>   7. m. y f. Jurista de una institución pública encargado de estudiar y preparar sus dictámenes o resoluciones. *Letrado del Consejo de Estado, del Tribunal Constitucional.*
>   8. m. y f. Asesor jurídico permanente de una sociedad o empresa.

[**Jurisconsulto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MeGEvHp)

> 1. m. y f. Persona dedicada al estudio, interpretación y aplicación del derecho.

propuesto por [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1674/fedorqui) en los comentarios también implica una actividad ("aplicación del derecho").

En otras profesiones sí existe una palabra para designar a la persona legalmente autorizada para ejercer esa profesión, independientemente de que lo haga o no, por ejemplo [**médico**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ol43qKz), [**arquitecto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3dtR7rK), [**veterinario**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bi2iFp6).

¿Existe alguna palabra para designar al "licenciado en derecho **que no ejerce profesionalmente**"?

Empiezo a sospechar que no, ya que, por ejemplo, [La Vanguardia](http://www.lavanguardia.com/temas) habla de Mariano Rajoy como "Licenciado en Derecho, durante el Gobierno de Aznar ..."

Comment: Para estos casos yo diría _Licenciado/Graduado en Derecho_. [Jurisconsulto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MeGEvHp) también tiene su punto.

Comment: La licenciatura en derecho son los estudios que te permiten trabajar como Jurista. Si estás habilitado (colegiado, etc) entonces podrás ser abogado.

El término correcto para un licenciado en derecho que trabaja en temas jurídicos es "jurista". Si además está habilitado para la defensa entonces es abogado.

Comment: El hecho de trabajar o no,  no cambia el nombre de la profesión. Esa persona se graduó de una institución y ahí le dieron un diploma que dice cual es su título. Si es un Licenciado en Derecho que no ejerce, sigue siendo un Licenciado en Derecho (desempleado, jubilado, en vacaciones, etc).

Comment: 1) No creo que exista una forma corta de decirlo explícitamente 2) Mi deformación profesional me obliga a repetir que el de abogado es un *título profesional* y que la licenciatura es un *grado académico* (que habitualmente se obtiene antes y es prerequisito). *En ese sentido particular*, el licenciado ni es necesariamente abogado ni necesariamente ejerce. Opino que la elección de *licenciado en derecho* deja suficientemente sembrada la duda de porqué no se prefirió *abogado*. No lo pongo como respuesta porque creo que no responde totalmente la pregunta (aparte de faltar referencias).

Comment: Creo que sencillamente no existe un término que diga eso: que se graduó en derecho pero no (necesariamente) ejerce, salvo las frases: _«licenciado en derecho»_, _«con título de abogado»_, etc. y la aclaración _«pero no ejerce»_.

En Colombia simplemente se diría abogado: _«El taxista que me llevó era abogado.»_ Es también lo que dice el diploma. Pero esta costumbre puede variar por país.

Comment: @user En todas las carreras profesionales que conducen a título, primero hay un grado de licenciado (ingeniería, medicina, etc.). De ahí que si se menciona el título se presume el grado y no al revés. La sola mención del grado sugiere la ausencia del título, salvo en contextos muy específicos (o postgrados, lógicamente).

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo dejaria como *Graduado/Licenciado en Derecho*.

En el momento que quiere incorporarse a un Colegio, existe el estado (y aceptado) de *Colegiado Ejerciente* y *Colegiado No Ejerciente*.

Se puede ver esta definición en el colegio de abogados de Madrid, Barcelona y en el Estatuto General de la Abogacia (articulo 9.1 y 13.1).

Asi pues para el no colegiado no habrá ese estado.

En la web del [ICAB - Información colegiación con título Español- NO EJERCIENTE](http://www.icab.es/?go=eaf9d1a0ec5f1dc58757ad6cffdacedb1a58854a600312ccb08705c7052b3548defa77ffbeed6568d0e6c0958b0ffc2a183cf3036eeec581):

> Son personas colegiadas no ejercientes aquellas se incorporan en el
>   Colegio sin intención de ejercer la abogacía, sino para disfrutar de
>   otros derechos inherentes a la condición de la persona colegiada.
>
> La documentación que deberá aportar para colegiarse como colegiado/da
>   no ejerciente es la siguiente:
>
> - Formularios facilitados  por el Colegio, debidamente cumplimentad
>
>   - [...]
>   - Juramento deontológico
>   - [...]
>   - Solicitud de certificación incorporación como colegiado/da no ejerciente del Consejo General de la Abogacía Española
> - Título habilitante:
>
>   - Para **Graduados en Derecho**: Acreditación del título profesional de abogado/a regulado en la Ley 34/200, de 30 de octubre (original y fotocopia).
>   - Para **licenciados/as en Derecho** antes del 31 de octubre de 2011: Acreditación del título profesional de abogado/a regulado en la Ley 34/200, de 30 de octubre (original y fotocopia).
>   - Para **licenciados/as en Derecho** después del  31 de octubre de 2011, siempre que se colegien en el plazo de dos años des del momento en que se encuentren en condiciones de solicitar la expedición del título oficial de licenciado en Derecho: Acreditación del Título de licenciado/da en Derecho con expresa mención de la fecha de finalización de los estudios (original y fotocopia). 
>       [...]

Comment: Sí, creo que _Licenciado/Graduado/<el título que inventen más adelante> en Derecho_ es lo más entendible.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que hay cierta ambigüedad en las definiciones del DRAE, por las que en algún momento **abogado**, **letrado** y **legista** se usaron en este sentido durante un tiempo.

En tu pregunta indicas ya la referencia de que el DRAE menciona:

> [**letrado**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NAwog2I)
> 6. m. y f. abogado (‖ licenciado en derecho).

Observamos la asociación del término *abogado* con *licenciado en derecho* sin más (o eso es lo que yo entiendo al referenciar una definición sinónima con `||`).

Mirando en el [Mapa de diccionarios](http://se%20us%C3%B3%20como%20tal%20durante%20un%20tiempo) veo que el diccionario de 1992 definía esta misma acepción de *letrado* (la sexta) como:

> m. y f. Abogado, titulado en derecho.

Por lo que por aquel entonces lo asociaba a la posesión del título, sin más.

Su uso está bajando, como indica [su página](http://iedra.es/palabras/letrado) en el DIRAE:

[image]

---

Por otra lado, observo la palabra *legista*:

> [**legista**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=N4lz6Gt)
> *Del lat. lex, legis 'ley' e -ista.*

1. m. y f. Persona versada en leyes o profesor de leyes o de jurisprudencia.
2. m. y f. Persona que estudia jurisprudencia o leyes.

En el [DIRAE](http://iedra.es/palabras/legista) vemos cómo su uso es bastante residual actualmente:

[image]